# iOS 13 Beta - Camera Capture Saving Photos in Wrong Orientation

Tags: swift, camera, avfoundation, ios13

With iOS 13 Beta, when a photo is captured, photos are saved in the wrong orientation.  They seem to be rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

We use all the native API methods and everything worked properly before iOS 13.  Before each capture capture, we run:

```
self.photoOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)!.videoOrientation = self.stillImageOrientation
```

This happens if I run an iOS 12 targeted build or iOS 13 Beta targeted build.

### UPDATE

This seems to be a HEIF format saving issue.

Comment: same problem facing.

Comment: Newly updated sample code for iOS 13, AVCAM, also saves photos in wrong orientation as described above.

Comment: Probably a bug, have you already filed a bug report?

Comment: @Brandon I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed on Beta 5.

Answer (score -1):

Update to beta 4 and the problem goes away

Comment: for me it is still reproducible on beta 4 but only in Portrait mode.

Comment: It's still present in Beta 4.  Seems to be present with HEIF capture.  JPEG capture seems to be fine.